# WTForm - QuerySelectField doesn't take the given/default value from database. Flask - WTForms - Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I use a wtform for both adding and editing an object and I use the queryselectfield for the foreign keys. The queryselectfield always takes the first value in the row. The correct value is actually passed right as far as I understand, it just doesn't take it for some reason.

**Model e.g.:**

```
class State(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'state'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    factor = db.Column(db.Float)
    time_created = db.Column(DateTime(timezone=True),
                             server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = db.Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())

    def __init__(self, country_id, name, factor):
        self.country_id = country_id
        self.name = name
        self.factor = factor

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.country_id, self.name)
```

**Model Country**

```
class Country(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'country'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    shortcut = db.Column(db.String(3))
    states = db.relationship('State', backref='country', lazy=True)
    time_created = db.Column(DateTime(timezone=True),
                             server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = db.Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())

    def __init__(self, name, shortcut):
        self.name = name
        self.shortcut = shortcut

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} - {} - {}'.format(self.id, self.name, self.shortcut)
```

**View:**

```
@admin_blueprint.route('/admin/state/edit/<int:state_id>',
                       methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_state(state_id):
    """Edit state"""
    obj = State.query.filter_by(id=state_id).first_or_404()
    form = StateForm(obj=obj)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit:
        obj.country_id = form.country_id.data.id
        obj.name = form.name.data
        obj.factor = form.factor.data
        db.session.commit()
        log_entry_edit(State, obj)
        return redirect(url_for('admin.list_states'))
    return render_template('admin/state_form.html', form=form,
                           title='Edit State')
```

**Form:**

```
def countries():
    return Country.query

class StateForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('State Name')
    factor = FloatField('Factor')
    country_id = QuerySelectField('Country', query_factory=countries)
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

**Template:**

```
    <div>
         {{ form.country_id.label }} 
         {{ form.country_id(class="form-control form-group") }}
         <output style="color: red;"  for="country_id" id="selected-country_id">
              ACTUAL ID: {{ form.country_id.data }}
         </output>
    </div>
    {% if form.country_id.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in country_id.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

As u can see in following image, the form takes the first value and it will also overwrite the db if I don't select again the value I wanted in the first place. 
The actual correct value arrives to the form though (ID in red):

[screenshot of template output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUeFv.png)

I just started working with flask, wtforms, etc and I honestly can't see what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: please provide 'Country' model class also.

Comment: Ok, I added it in the question

Comment: I realize its been 4 years but did you fix this problem - with the suggested solution or other? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and finally figured it out: you have to separately get the data for the foreign key when calling in the form ('GET'), before you set it with 'POST':

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form.country_id.data = obj.country_id
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit:
    # as before
```